# Unable to draw multiple lines at once

Tags: java, swing

This is my Code...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class LineDrawing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createWindow();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createWindow() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

        mainFrame.add(new myPanel());
        mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.white);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class myPanel extends JPanel {
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int endX;
    int endY;

    public myPanel() {

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                startX = e.getX();
                startY = e.getY();
                repaint(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                endX = e.getX();
                endY = e.getY();
                repaint(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                startX = e.getX();
                endX = startX;
                startY = e.getY();
                endY = startY;
                repaint(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                endX = e.getX();
                endY = e.getY();
                repaint(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

I am trying to draw multiple lines while keeping the former ones still existing on the screen(frame)...
 But when I click again the previous line gets rubbed or erased away...

I am trying to design a graph analysing app(which will tell whether the entered graphs are isomorphic or not...

My problem is that I am not able to draw multiple lines but only one line...

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the 2 common ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that I am not able to draw multiple lines but only one line...

It is drawing 1 line only because you only drew 1 line in your paintComponent.
Note that the drawings will ***not*** be accumulative.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine(startX,startY,endX,endY);  //this will draw only one line..
    repaint();                            //do not do this!
}
```

To draw multiple lines such as a graph you need a data structure to hold the data of each plot. Then you can iterate though it and draw multiple lines from there.

So instead only maintaining only 1 set of plot `(startX, startY, endX, endY)`. You can create a class for Plot:

```
public class Plot
{
    private int startX;
    private int startY;
    private int endX;
    private int endY;

    public Plot(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY){
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.endX = endX ;
        this.endY = endY ;
    }

    public void draw(Grpahics g){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(startX,startY,endX,endY);        
    }
}
```

Then in your display panel, keep a list of Plots:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    private ArrayList<Plot> plots;

    public MyPanel(){
        plots = new ArrayList<Plot>();
    }

    public void addPlot(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
         plots.add(new Plot(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    }

    //Invoke addPlot() in your mouseListener after you get startXY & endXY
    //Invoke repaint() after addPlot()
    //Don't have to do this: "repaint(startX,startY,endX,endY);"
}
```

Then finally, in your `paintComponent()`:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(Plot p : plots)
        p.draw(g);        //Each plot will draw itself
}
```

Furthermore, you should not be calling `repaint()`  within `paintComponent()`. You can call it outside `paintComponent()` when you need to refresh your screen.